# Changing pom.xml doesn't update libraries in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, m2eclipse

I have pom.xml like this:

```
...

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

...
```

When I change `spring.version` into 3.2.2.RELEASE, nothing happens. I still have 3.0.5.RELEASE under Libraries build path.

I am using Eclipse Indigo SR2 with m2eclipse.

EDIT: Please mind, I am a newbie in maven world.

Comment: You need to update the project configuration manually. **Project -> Maven -> Update Configuration**.

Comment: I don't have this option.

Comment: Maybe it can't download the 3.2.2.RELEASE. Open a brand new project, put only (like this) `<dependency><groupId>org.springframework</groupId><artifactId>spring-core</artifactId><version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version></dependency>` and see if it gets the version without errors.

Comment: @Trick Check if you have an entry Project -> Maven ? If yes there should be something like **Project** or **Configuration**. Furthermore better update to Juno Eclipse and install m2e.

Comment: @acdcjunior, in other project it did download without errors

Comment: Check it on command line what's happening. **mvn clean package**

Comment: Ok, I figured it... Your comment helped, @khmarbaise, when I went to Project-Configure, there was a "Convert to Maven project". That was missing. Thanks! Add this to your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to update the project configuration manually. Project -> Maven -> Update Configuration

**Update**:
Also set checkbox: **Update Project Configuration from pom**

Comment: I don't have this option. Not on the right click on project or in the menu bar Project...

Comment: If the `Maven` option is missing, you need to convert the project to a maven project first. _Right click, Configure -> Convert to to Maven project_

Answer (score 7):

Right-click on any project in the package explorer then select Maven. In maven select Update Project.  or simply  Alt + F5

Comment: In addition to the above, I have to select: Force Update of Releases/Snapshot and Update project configuration from pom.xml.